# Perl's BEGIN blocks in app.psgi

Tags: perl, psgi

I understand that the BEGIN is executed before the main program. The questions are:

- what is the *main program* when talking about an PGSI application - or better
- when will be executed the BEGIN block in an PGSI app?
- It is different for `plackup` or `Starman` and like?
- What about the middlewares - when have **multiple** BEGIN blocks?

Example `app.psgi`:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use YAML;
use Plack::Builder;
use CGI::Emulate::PSGI;

our($cfg);

BEGIN {
    $cfg = YAML::LoadFile("my.config");
}

#old really __BIG__ cgi application - what uses many BEGIN blocks too...
my $app1 = CGI::Emulate::PSGI->handler(sub {
    use My::CgiApp1;
    My::CgiApp1::executer->run();
});
my $app2 = sub { ... };

builder {
    mount "/path1" => $app1;
    mount "/"      => $app2;
}
```

In what order will be executed the multiple BEGIN blocks what are defined in `My::CgiApp1` and my `app.pgsi`?

From the above PSGI application's point of view what is the main difference using:

```
BEGIN {
    $cfg = YAML::LoadFile("my.config");
}
```

or an simple

```
$cfg = YAML::LoadFile("my.config");
```

Answer (score 4):

`BEGIN` blocks are executed during the *compilation* phase immediately the end of the block is seen by the compiler.

That means each `BEGIN` block is executed only *once*, before the main run starts, and the blocks are executed in the order the compiler sees them.

Remember that a `use` statement is essentially `require` in a hidden `BEGIN` block, so in your case the compiler will process the main program, executing the `YAML::LoadFile` as soon as the closing brace of its `BEGIN` block is seen. Then it will continue compiling the program until `use My::CgiApp1`, when it will suspend processing the main program and start to compile `My/CgiApp1.pm`.

Perl will now execute any `BEGIN` blocks it finds in this file as they are encountered, and similarly suspend processing in the case of any further `use` statements.

As soon as the module specified in any `use` statement has finished compilation, processing will continue in the original file with next line of code.

All of this happens before `My::CgiApp1::executer->run` is executed, which is an ordinary statement and so is performed at run time.